How to pass bot instance into handlers file in aiogram?
I'm making a modular bot using aiogram and want to make it typing while generating answer
This is what I found in official docs:
async with ChatActionSender.typing(bot=bot, chat_id=message.chat.id):
    # Do something...
    # Perform some long calculations
    await message.answer(result)

However, it needs a bot variable which I don't have in handlers.py file and can't import (it causes ImportError)

... so what is the question? What error occurs?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


Specify 'typing' action for 5 seconds

Inside your handler do this:
@router.message()
async def bot_typing_action_test(message: Message):
    await message.bot.send_chat_action(chat_id=call.from_user.id, action="typing")

This code sends the action 'typing...' into specified chat_id.
Source: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendchataction
Telegram API reference also specifies how you can send other actions, such as 'sending video...' or 'sending voice...'

Specify 'typing' action for the duration of some expensive calculation:

In such case, you can do as you did before. You can access bot instance from message:
async with ChatActionSender.typing(bot=message.bot, chat_id=message.chat.id):
    # Do something...
    # Perform some long calculations
    await message.answer(result)

